# what is the purpose of solid_i18n_patterns?

Tags: python, django, url-pattern

i am new to **python/django** and i just want to know the purpose of below function/code (`solid_i18n_patterns`).

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from solid_i18n.urls import solid_i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = 
solid_i18n_patterns(<appname.views>,<urlpattern>,<anotherurlpattern>.....) 
+ 
solid_i18n_patterns(<anotherappname.views>,<urlpattern>,<anotherurlpattern>.....)
```

what is the purpose of `solid_i18n_patterns` and its arguments?

Comment: What don't you understand in particular? Do you understand [regular url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/) in Django? Do you understand Django's built in [`i18n_patterns`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.conf.urls.i18n)? Have you looked at the [README](https://github.com/st4lk/django-solid-i18n-urls/blob/master/README.md) for the solid_i18n app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solid_i18n is a helper package for internationalization.
Suppose you have an English website and you want to serve it also in French. By default, If you make your site bilingual, you should specify language code at the beginning of your URLs:

```
www.example.com/en/* - serves English
www.example.com/fr/* - serves French
```

With solid_i18n_patterns, you can serve your default language without language code in URL.

```
www.example.com/* - serves English (note no /en/ in URL)
www.example.com/fr/* - serves French
```